# How can I delete specific <li> item from the list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a to do list with HTML, CSS and JS but I can not add `delete` function. I wanna hold these tasks in localStorage at the same time. When I click second item's delete button, always first item gets deleted. What can I do?

Basically, I want to seperate `li`'s with `[data-text=tasklist[i]` and delete the `li` item that has attribute or when clicked.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <title>To Do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- Toast start Task -->
<div class="position-fixed bottom-0 right-0 p-3" 
style="z-index: 5; right: 0; top: 0;">
  <div id="liveToast" class="toast hide" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" 
  aria-atomic="true" data-delay="6000">
    <div class="toast-header">
      <strong class="mr-auto">Kodluyoruz </strong>
      <span id="toast-img"></span>
      <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" 
      aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body font-weight-bold">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Toast End For task -->
    <!-- Container Start -->
    <div class="container col-sm-8  mt-5">
      <div class="row text-center  d-block">
        <!-- Header Start -->
        <div class="header my-3 rounded ">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/9kdepi1d/production/65c832d202a503b15d99e628f4313782f3ef50db-300x62.png"
            class="mb-1"
            alt=""
          />
          <h2>To Do List</h2>
        
          <div id="searchBar" class="input-group">
            
            <input class="input-group rounded-left d-inline" type="text" 
            name="task" id="task" placeholder="Bugün ne yapacaksın?" />
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="newElement()" id="liveToastBtn">Ekle</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Header End -->
      <!-- Task List Start -->
        <ul class="list-group" id="list">
        </ul>
        <!-- Task List End -->
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script
          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Container End -->
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```js
var TASK = document.querySelector('#task');
let ulEl = document.querySelector('#list');
const toastEl = document.querySelector('#liveToast');
const toastBody = document.querySelector('.toast-body');
const toastImg = document.querySelector('#toast-img');
let collapseBtn = `<button id="clsBtn" onclick="deleteTask()" type="button" class="close" 
data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>`
let taskList = !localStorage.getItem('tasks') ?  [] : (localStorage.getItem('tasks').split(','));
console.log(taskList)
console.log(taskList.length)
// get the list of tasks in local storage
if(taskList.length>0){
    for (let i=0; i < taskList.length; i++) {
        if(checkForText(taskList[i])){
            TASK.value = taskList[i];
            const liDOM = document.createElement('li');
            liDOM.innerHTML = `${TASK.value} ${collapseBtn}`;
            liDOM.classList.add('list-group-item','d-flex', 
            'justify-content-between', 'align-items-center');
            liDOM.setAttribute('data-text',TASK.value);
            ulEl.append(liDOM);
            TASK.value = '';
        }
    }
}
// check for <text> is in the list?
function checkForText(text) {
    let found = false;
    if(taskList.includes(text.toLowerCase())) {
            found = true;
        }                
        return found;       
}
// add new Task
function newElement (){
    console.log(TASK.value);
    console.log("running");
    const liDOM = document.createElement('li');
    if (TASK.value.length > 0){
        if(checkForText(TASK.value)){
            //toast
            toastBody.innerHTML = `<p class= "text-danger">
            Eklemek istediğiniz görev listede mevcut!!</p>`
            toastImg.innerHTML = `<img id="toastImg" style="width: 5px;" 
            src="img/exclamation-solid.svg" class="rounded mr-2" alt="">`
            //Showing and Hiding Toast automatically -JQuery
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#liveToast').toast('show');
            });
            TASK.value= '';
        }else{
            liDOM.innerHTML = `${TASK.value} ${collapseBtn}`;
            liDOM.classList.add('list-group-item','d-flex', 
            'justify-content-between', 'align-items-center');
            liDOM.setAttribute('data-text',TASK.value);
            ulEl.append(liDOM);
            taskList.push(TASK.value.trim());
            localStorage.setItem('tasks',(taskList));
            //************************************ */

            // toast
            toastBody.innerHTML = `<p class= "text-success">Görev listeye eklendi.</p>`;
            toastImg.innerHTML = `<img id="toastImg" style="width: 15px;" 
            src="img/check-solid.svg" class="rounded mr-2" alt="">`
            //Showing and Hiding Toast automatically -JQuery
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#liveToast').toast('show');
            });

            TASK.value= '';
        }
    }else if (TASK.value.length <1 ){
        // toast
        toastBody.innerHTML = `<p class= "text-danger">Listeye boş ekleme yapamazsınız!!</p>`
        toastImg.innerHTML = `<img id="toastImg" style="width: 5px;" 
        src="img/exclamation-solid.svg" class="rounded mr-2" alt="">`
        //Showing and Hiding Toast automatically -JQuery
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#liveToast').toast('show');
        });
        // toastEl.classList.replace('hide', 'show');
        // await sleep (7000);
        // toastEl.classList.replace( 'show', 'hide');
        
    }

}


// delete Task
//if(localStorage.getItem('tasks').length > 0 || taskList.length > 0 ){
function deleteTask(){
    let liEl = document.querySelectorAll('.list-group-item');
    let i = 0;
    for(; i < taskList.length; i++){
        if(liEl("data-text") === taskList[i]){
            // taskList.splice(taskList.indexOf(taskList[i]), 1);
            // liEl.querySelector(`[data-text="${taskList[i]}"]`).removeChild();
console.log( "attr"+liEl.getAttribute("data-text"));

            localStorage.setItem('tasks', taskList);
            // console.log(taskList);
            // console.log(localStorage.getItem('tasks'))
        }
    }
    



}
```

CSS:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  list-style-type: none;

  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

ul li.checked {
  background: #276678;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

ul li.checked::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f78501;
  color: white;

}

.header {
  background-color: #f78501;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  background-color: white;
}

.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

#task {
  width: 94%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution if anyone need.
Firstly, i create a node list with css attribute selector. (line 98 app.js)
Then i added event listener with for loop (line 100 app.js)
Only bad side of this solution, page have to reload with 'location.reload' function when add a new task. Here all codes:

```
var TASK = document.querySelector('#task');
let ulEl = document.querySelector('#list');
const toastEl = document.querySelector('#liveToast');
const toastBody = document.querySelector('.toast-body');
const toastImg = document.querySelector('#toast-img');
let collapseBtn = `<button data-delete="cls" class= "Btn rounded small border-secondary" type="button" class="close" 
data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
<span class=" font-weight-bold" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>`
let taskList = !localStorage.getItem('tasks') ?  [] : (localStorage.getItem('tasks').split(','));
console.log(taskList)
console.log(taskList.length)
//get the list of tasks in local storage
if(taskList.length>0){
    for (let i=0; i < taskList.length; i++) {
        if(checkForText(taskList[i])){
            TASK.value = taskList[i];
            const liDOM = document.createElement('li');
            liDOM.innerHTML = `<p>${TASK.value}</p> ${collapseBtn}`;
            liDOM.classList.add('list-group-item','d-flex', 
            'justify-content-between', 'align-items-center');
            liDOM.setAttribute('data-text',TASK.value);
            ulEl.append(liDOM);
            TASK.value = '';
        }
    }
}
//check for 'text' is in the list?
function checkForText(text) {
    let found = false;
    if(taskList.includes(text.toLowerCase())) {
            found = true;
        }                
        return found;       
}
//Add new Task
async function newElement (){
    console.log(TASK.value);
    console.log("running");
    const liDOM = document.createElement('li');
    if (TASK.value.length > 0){     //if value length is greater than zero
        if(checkForText(TASK.value)){   //if value is already in the list
            //toast
            toastBody.innerHTML = `<p class= "text-danger">
            Eklemek istediğiniz görev listede mevcut!!</p>`
            toastImg.innerHTML = `<img id="toastImg" style="width: 5px;" 
            src="img/exclamation-solid.svg" class="rounded mr-2" alt="">`
            //Showing and Hiding Toast automatically -JQuery
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#liveToast').toast('show');
            });
            TASK.value= '';
        }else{          //if value is not in the list, add it to the list
            liDOM.innerHTML = `<p>${TASK.value}</p> ${collapseBtn}`;
            liDOM.classList.add('list-group-item','d-flex', 
            'justify-content-between', 'align-items-center');
            liDOM.setAttribute('data-text',TASK.value);
            ulEl.append(liDOM);
            taskList.push(TASK.value.trim());
            localStorage.setItem('tasks',(taskList));
            //************************************ */

            //toast
            toastBody.innerHTML = `<p class= "text-success">Görev listeye eklendi.</p>`;
            toastImg.innerHTML = `<img id="toastImg" style="width: 15px;" 
            src="img/check-solid.svg" class="rounded mr-2" alt="">`
            //Showing and Hiding Toast automatically -JQuery
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#liveToast').toast('show');
            });
            TASK.value= '';
            //working like sleep function
            await new Promise(done => setTimeout(() => done(), 3000));
            //reload page for close button - addEventListener(deleteTask)
            location.reload();
        }
    }else if (TASK.value.length <1 ){   // if value length is smaller than one
        // toast
        toastBody.innerHTML = `<p class= "text-danger">Listeye boş ekleme yapamazsınız!!</p>`
        toastImg.innerHTML = `<img id="toastImg" style="width: 5px;" 
        src="img/exclamation-solid.svg" class="rounded mr-2" alt="">`
        //Showing and Hiding Toast automatically -JQuery
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#liveToast').toast('show');
        });
        // toastEl.classList.replace('hide', 'show');
        // await sleep (4000);
        // toastEl.classList.replace( 'show', 'hide');
        
    }
    
    
}


//Delete Task
if(taskList.length > 0 ){
    let clsBtn = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-delete="cls"]`)
    let i = 0;
    for(; i < clsBtn.length; i++){
        clsBtn[i].addEventListener('click', deleteTask)
    }
    function deleteTask(){
        let txt = this.parentElement.querySelector('p')
        taskList.splice(taskList.indexOf(txt.innerText),1);
        this.parentElement.remove();
        localStorage.setItem('tasks',taskList);
        }    
}
```